# How to custom my own jmeter plugins path

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I want to add the additional plugin to the jmeter ,but putting all the plugin into ${JMETER_HOME}/lib is not easy to manage .

So I want to put those plugins into a custom folder .

I read the document of jmeter then set

```
 search_paths=../myPlugins/jpgc-graphs-basic-2.0/lib
```

restart the jmeter 
but the new plugin  still not show in the listener list .
[image: the folder tree]

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of the plugin installation should look like:

1. Put `jmeter-plugins-graphs-basic-2.0.jar` to `lib/ext` folder of your JMeter installation
2. Put `jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.3.jar` to `lib` folder of your JMeter installation.

If for some reason you don't want or cannot use `lib` and `lib/ext` folders and would like to override JMeter plugins search paths your configuration should look like:

```
search_paths=../myPlugins/jpgc-graphs-basic-2.0/lib/ext
user.classpath=../myPlugins/jpgc-graphs-basic-2.0/lib
```

References:

- [JMeter's Classpath](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)